# Output for stargazer in R

Tags: r, matlab, stargazer

I follow the instruction of [this article](http://cran.at.r-project.org/web/packages/stargazer/vignettes/stargazer.pdf)

```
> library(stargazer)
> stargazer(attitude)

% Table created by stargazer v.5.0 by Marek Hlavac, Harvard University. E-mail: hlavac at fas.harvard.edu
% Date and time: Fri, Mar 07, 2014 - 4:12:55 PM
\begin{table}[!htbp] \centering 
  \caption{} 
  \label{} 
\begin{tabular}{@{\extracolsep{5pt}}lccccc} 
\\[-1.8ex]\hline 
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
Statistic & \multicolumn{1}{c}{N} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Mean} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{St. Dev.} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Min} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Max} \\ 
rating & 30 & 64.633 & 12.173 & 40 & 85 \\ 
complaints & 30 & 66.600 & 13.315 & 37 & 90 \\ 
privileges & 30 & 53.133 & 12.235 & 30 & 83 \\ 
learning & 30 & 56.367 & 11.737 & 34 & 75 \\ 
raises & 30 & 64.633 & 10.397 & 43 & 88 \\ 
critical & 30 & 74.767 & 9.895 & 49 & 92 \\ 
advance & 30 & 42.933 & 10.289 & 25 & 72 \\ 
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
\end{tabular} 
\end{table} 
>
```

I cannot see the output table in R windows. **Where I can access the table?**

Comment: This is LaTeX code. You'll need an interpreter to translate it into something more readable, like a pdf. On windows, I use MikTeX. Another option is Markdown (see for example http://rpubs.com/Thell/xtable).

Comment: A look at [**`knitr`**](http://yihui.name/knitr/) may also be relevant.

Comment: You could also use LyX editor. Insert a Latex block there, paste your text and compile the document. If you've never used LaTeX this would probably be the easiest way.

Comment: okay. i get it. so it will the same for html that i copy and paste the result to txt file and save as .html. Is there any way that the output directly shown in R windows?

Comment: Nope. R can basically only render plain text. You can use the `browseURL` function or calls to `system` to open compiled knitr output in an appropriate viewer (e.g., web browser or PDF viewer).

Comment: Many thanks for all the gentle help!

Answer (score 0):

Check the help file for `? Stargazer`.  If you want to view the table *in* the R environment and have it be plainly readable use the `type="text"` argument.

My guess is that isn't the desire and you'd like to make use of the pretty table in a document.  The `type="latex" is what you want if your creating a`sweave`document and`type="html"` works nicely for markdown documents.

The simplest thing to do is install the [RStudio](https://www.rstudio.com/ide/) application and the [knitr](http://yihui.name/knitr/) package, then create  a new `sweave` or `markdown` document.  If you choose `sweave` you'll also need a [Latex distribution](http://latex-project.org/ftp.html#distributions) installed to render the document.

The easiest route is RStudio -> New Markdown File -> paste this into the file:

````
```{r, results='asis'}
require(stargazer)
stargazer(attitude, type="html")
```
````

The click the 'Knit HTML' button and look at your table.

***Enjoy!***